# Exception in thread "main" org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException: permission denied

Tags: java, selenium, firefox

This code is not running even when i find nothing wrong.

[image]

Comment: Would like to suggest you to provide code snippet in here itself instead of the image. It is not good practice to ask questions using image and expect  answers

Comment: make sure your user have read write access for gecodriver.exe also make sure your anti virus is not preventing you from copying the gecodriver.exe.

Answer (score 0):

Please make sure the mentioned path i.e. E:/ is accessible.

One of the solution is try to move gecko into some other directory.

```
driver = webdriver.Firefox('<new directory>/geckodriver.exe')
```